# Async method deadlocks with TestScheduler in ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I'm trying to use the reactiveui test scheduler with an async method in a test.

The test hangs when the async call is awaited.

The root cause seems to be a command that's awaited in the async method.

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
        => await new TestScheduler().With(async scheduler =>
        {
            await SomeAsyncMethod();

            // *** execution never gets here
            Debugger.Break();
        });

    private async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
    {
        var command = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        });

        // *** this hangs
        await command.Execute();
    }
```

How can I do an async call in combination with the test scheduler that does not deadlock?

I'm using reactiveui 9.4.1

**EDIT:**

I've tried the `WithAsync()` method as suggested in Funks answer, but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Just for troubleshooting, what happens when `SomeAsyncMethod` just returns a completed task? Trying to narrow down the problem scope (divide and conquer)

Comment: @Nkosi if I change the method to be not async to return a completed task, then I can't await the execution of the command

Comment: No. Forget the command for now. I was referring to `private Task SomeAsyncMethod() { return Task.CompletedTask; }` to see if it would still hang as implied in the first snippet.

Comment: @Nkosi ok I see - it only hangs when I await the command, just awaiting `Task.Delay(100)` doesn't hang

Comment: Ok so acknowledging `WithAsync` is the preferred approach, (as you are attempting to work with async), we now need to check `ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask` to see if it is making any blocking calls internally that would cause a deadlock

Comment: @Nkosi well the command creation doesn't hang, just the part when the command execution gets awaited. Even if the command body itself has no awaited code the command execution will hang

Comment: Ok will need to review the source to confirm if a blocking call is being made https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/502963d37c59766c601bf6ac5349c63a461b9eb6/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand/ReactiveCommand.cs#L647

Comment: Ok so I created a project to reproduce the problem and was having an issue with it recognizing `await command.Execute()`. So as a work around I just did not await the command and instead returned a completed task and ran the test, which worked. Not sure if this is a false positive because of that syntax error I was receiving earlier.

Comment: @Nkosi the cause of the hang is the awaiting of the executed command. I made my question clearer to reflect that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I do an async call in combination with the test scheduler?

**In short**

`command.Execute()` is a cold observable. You need to subscribe to it, instead of using `await`.

Given your interest in `TestScheduler`, I take it you want to test something involving time. However, from the [When should I care about scheduling](https://pasoft-sharereactiveui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/schedulers/) section:

> threads created via "new Thread()" or "Task.Run" can't be controlled in a unit test.

So, if you want to check, for example, if your `Task` completes within 100ms, you're going to have to wait until the async method completes. To be sure, that's *not* the kind of test `TestScheduler` is meant for.

**The somewhat longer version**

The purpose of `TestScheduler` is to verify workflows by putting things in motion and verifying state at certain points in time. As we can only manipulate time on a `TestScheduler`, you'd typically prefer not to wait on real async code to complete, given there's no way to fast forward actual computations or I/O. Remember, it's about verifying workflows: `vm.A` has new value at 20ms, so `vm.B` should have new val at 120ms,...

So how can you test the SUT?

**1\ You could mock the async method using `scheduler.CreateColdObservable`**

```
public class ViewModelTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        string observed = "";

        new TestScheduler().With(scheduler =>
        {
            var observable = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
                scheduler.OnNextAt(100, "Done"));

            observable.Subscribe(value => observed = value);
            Assert.Equal("", observed);

            scheduler.AdvanceByMs(99);
            Assert.Equal("", observed);

            scheduler.AdvanceByMs(1);
            Assert.Equal("Done", observed);
        });
    }
}
```

Here we basically replaced `command.Execute()` with `var observable` created on `scheduler`.

It's clear the example above is rather simple, but with several observables notifying each other this kind of test can provide valuable insights, as well as a safety net while refactoring.

Ref:

- [Answer by Paul Betts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486541/reactiveui-testing-observable-properties-from-unit-tests#comment20193716_14489426)
- [Control Time with the `TestScheduler`](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/03/10/master-time-with-reactive-extensions/)

**2\ You could reference the `IScheduler` explicitly**

a) Using the schedulers provided by [RxApp](https://reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui/rxapp/)

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public string Observed { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Observed = "";

        this.MyCommand = ReactiveCommand
            .CreateFromTask(SomeAsyncMethod);
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> MyCommand { get; }

    private async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
    {
        await RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        Observed = "Done";
    }
}

public class ViewModelTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        new TestScheduler().With(scheduler =>
        {
            var vm = new MyViewModel();

            vm.MyCommand.Execute().Subscribe();
            Assert.Equal("", vm.Observed);

            scheduler.AdvanceByMs(99);
            Assert.Equal("", vm.Observed);

            scheduler.AdvanceByMs(1);
            Assert.Equal("Done", vm.Observed);
        });
    }
}
```

Note

- `CreateFromTask` creates a `ReactiveCommand` with asynchronous execution logic. There's no need to define the `Test` method as async or await the `TestScheduler`.
- Within the `With` extension method's scope `RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler` = `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` =  the `new TestScheduler()`.

b) Managing your own schedulers through constructor injection

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly IScheduler _taskpoolScheduler;
    public string Observed { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        _taskpoolScheduler = scheduler;
        Observed = "";

        this.MyCommand = ReactiveCommand
            .CreateFromTask(SomeAsyncMethod);
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> MyCommand { get; }

    private async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
    {
        await _taskpoolScheduler.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        Observed = "Done";
    }
}

public class ViewModelTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        new TestScheduler().With(scheduler =>
        {
            var vm = new MyViewModel(scheduler); ;

            vm.MyCommand.Execute().Subscribe();
            Assert.Equal("", vm.Observed);

            scheduler.AdvanceByMs(99);
            Assert.Equal("", vm.Observed);

            scheduler.AdvanceByMs(0);
            Assert.Equal("Done", vm.Observed);
        });
    }
}
```

Ref:

- [Kent Boogaert's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424718/recommended-way-to-test-scheduler-throttle#comment73923478_43425990)
- [Testing Rx code - ISchedulerProvider](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html)

Let's close ranks with another quote from Haacked:

> Unfortunately, and this next point is important, the `TestScheduler` doesn’t extend into real life, so your shenanigans are limited to your asynchronous Reactive code. Thus, if you call `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in your test, that thread will really be blocked for a second. But as far as the test scheduler is concerned, no time has passed.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys After digging a little deeper, I opted to revise my post.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use ConfigureAwait(false) when calling nested method?

```
 [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
        => await new TestScheduler().With(async scheduler =>
        {
            // this hangs
            await SomeAsyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(false);

            // ***** execution will never get to here
            Debugger.Break();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on all your async methods.
This will provide you non-blocking behavior.

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test()
    => await new TestScheduler().With(async scheduler =>
    {
        await SomeAsyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // *** execution never gets here
        Debugger.Break();
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

private async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
{
    var command = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // *** this hangs
    await command.Execute();
}
```

Another way to test whether the problem is related with ConfigureAwait is to port your project to Asp.Net Core  and test it there.

Asp.net core does not need to use ConfigureAwait to prevent this blocking issue.

[Check this for Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42058544/1118978)

Comment: this has been pointed out already in another answer, it still hangs unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please check my answer again?

Comment: it's not working, it has something to do with the reactiveui testscheduler

Comment: Did you tried with .Net core are is it just an assumption?  Did you read my edited answer?